# Incorrect string value: '\xF9'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, character-encoding

I'm trying to convert a vBulletin forum in phpBB .. In local everything went well with a sample forum, on the server instead I get this error:
code:

> SQL ERROR [ mysqli ]
>
> Incorrect string value: '\xF9' for column 'poll_option_text' at row 1
>   [1366]

Now, from what I read on the web, it is a coding error .. So I'm trying to change the encoding that column but the result does not change .. I always appears the same mistake ..
Am I doing something wrong?
Should I change the encoding to the database or table ..?

Comment: That could be Latin-1 or Windows-1252 data being interpreted as UTF-8.

Comment: Yes.. Much probably, but where I work to solve the problem..?

Comment: Where did the text come from?  How are you connecting to mysql?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: And look through other questions with [mysql] [character-encoding] tags.

Comment: poll (vBulletin)
chpoll
CREATE TABLE `chpoll` (
`question` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT '',
`options` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
`votes` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
PRIMARY KEY (`pollid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2231 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

phpbb_poll_options (phpBB)
phpbb_poll_options
CREATE TABLE `phpbb_poll_options` (
`poll_option_text` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
`poll_option_total` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
KEY `poll_opt_id` (`poll_option_id`),
KEY `topic_id` (`topic_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin